# How can i set htaccess file for virtual host?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-16.04, virtualhost

I created a virtual host with this code :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@127.0.0.1
    ServerName site.ws
    ServerAlias www.site.ws
    DocumentRoot /home/me/Projects/website/build
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /home/me/Projects/website/build>

        Allow from all
        Satisfy any

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and I created a .htaccess file in my /build directory with this code :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule   ^(.*)$    $1.html    [R,NC]
```

Consider my mod_rewrite is active in apache2, but I can't open pages with /filename

e.g site.ws/about

It shows error :
The requested URL /about was not found on this server.

Comment: Which version of Apache do you use?

Comment: @benny-ben apache2 - version 2.4.8 - 2017

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I try this with Apache2 2.4.27 in win:

First enable vhost in httpd.conf file.

vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.ws
    DocumentRoot /home/me/Projects/website/build
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /home/me/Projects/website/build>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
###START MOD_REWRITE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #REMOVE .html EXTENSION
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

</IfModule>
###END MOD_REWRITE
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem with :

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule   ^([a-zA-Z-]+)$ $1.html    [L,NC]
```

Comment: What differences did you find from my solution?